# (ASM) what does "set bit 1" mean?

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm learning MIPS assembly using a website for practice exercises.

> Exercise 2
>
> In each register $1 through $7 set the corresponding bit. **That is,
>   in register 1 set bit 1 (and clear the rest to zero), in $2 set bit 2
>   (and clear the rest to zero), and so on.** Use only one ori
>   instruction in your program, to set the bit in register $1.
>   start with:
>   'ori   $1,$0,0x01' 
>   Don't use any ori instructions other than that one.
>   Note: bit 1 of a register is the second from the right, the one that
>   (in unsigned binary) corresponds to the first power of two.

Can someone please explain this?

**Is it correct to put 0x02 in register 1?** 
(I can't use ori, so I would use a left shift to make the 0x01 into 0x02)

This makes register 1 == 10 (binary). Therefore the 1st bit of register 1 is a 1, and other bits are zero?

I'm confused because the MIPS simulator doesn't show the leading zeros. So I don't know if I'm doing this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your interpretation is correct.

```
ori $1,$0,0x01  # Initialize $1
sll $2,$1,2     # Set bit 2 or $2
sll $3,$1,3     # Set bit 3 of $3
...             # ..and so on for $4..$7
sll $1,$1,1     # Finally set bit 1 of $1
```

or alternatively:

```
ori $1,$0,0x01
sll $1,$1,1
sll $2,$1,1
sll $3,$2,1
...
```

Comment: Often people will also say "reset bit 1" which means "clear bit 1 and leave the rest alone"